# Calculate md5 with NSURLSessionDownloadTask for very large file

Tags: objective-c, md5, nsurl

NSURLConnection can be used to calculate the md5 on-the-fly:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
    // theData is a small piece
```

NSURLSessionDownloadTask is an "upgrade" of NSURLConnection. But how can we check the md5 without read through the whole file again after it is downloaded? Its interface is like:

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                     completionHandler:
^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // the whole file is downloaded and saved at location.
}];
```

The key requirement here is low memory footprint and the file has to be downloaded completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data to arrive in small NSData pieces that you can examine and append to a larger NSMutableData bit by bit, as you did with `connection:didReceiveData:`, ask for a [data task](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataTask_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of a download task.

You call `dataTaskWithRequest:`, supply a delegate, and start the data task (with `resume`) - and the delegate receives `URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:`, exactly like in the old NSURLConnection days.

Here's a complete working example (except that I don't tell you what to do with the bits of data as they arrive):

```
- (NSURLSession*) configureSession {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    config.allowsCellularAccess = NO;
    NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    return session;
}

- (IBAction) doHTTP: (id) sender {
    if (!self.session)
        self.session = [self configureSession];

    NSString* s = // some URL string
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
    NSMutableURLRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [[self session] dataTaskWithRequest:req];
    self.task = task;
    [task resume];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"received %lu bytes of data", (unsigned long)data.length);
    // do something with the data here!
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"completed; error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: the iOS might not have the memory to hold the NSMutableData when the download is close to finish.

Comment: Then do not append to an NSMutableData. Append to a file on disk! Just do whatever you were doing in the NSURLConnection days.

Comment: it will be in one of the followig two NSData(s)       - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler;
       - (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler;   So, it is still a memory issue.

Comment: Yes, if you call those methods. But you don't. You call `dataTaskWithRequest:`, and now your delegate is called back as each little chunk arrives, just as with NSURLConnection. I've edited my answer to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt said, you can use a data task, which lets you easily see the data as it is downloaded.

However, if you want to observe a download task, you can accomplish a similar thing if you are willing to take a few small risks.

I'm sure I'll get a million down votes for the following, but just remember... when you need a screwdriver, and all you have is a hammer, you flip the hammer over, and use it as a screwdriver... or bang on the screw so much that it turns into a nail...

First, I think the API is broken.  The delegates should provide at least one of these two things.  If you agree, file a radar.  The delegate should provide the temporary file (much less preferred - I think it should remain opaque) or it should provide the `NSData` that is being written in `URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` -- this is the right answer.

Anyway, if you are willing to use an **undocumented**, **unofficial** approach...

The temporary files are stored in `Library/Caches/com.apple.nsnetworkd/` so you can easily look in there and determine which files are being used as the temporary destination.

Or, you can, again **unofficially**, determine the temporary file by canceling the download with `cancelByProducingResumeData:` and then unarchiving the resume data blob -- the resume data blob is currently an archived dictionary -- and get the file path from the dictionary.  Then, you can resume the download, knowing which temporary file is being used for the download.

Anyway, once you have the file, inside your `URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` you can then just read the most recently written chunk from the file.

Now, having said that, you may want to just use a data task, because it will officially provide you the piece of data it just downloaded... but you **can** resort to this hack to get at the data that was downloaded to the file, if you must do a background download -- which must be down with a download task.

One problem you may have is that the file IO may be buffered, so what's been actually flushed (and available form a separate file descriptor) may be different from what has been reported in the delegate method.  You may just need to keep track of the last byte you read, and inside that delegate, just read from there to the current end of the file...

Your mileage will most certainly vary, but it will give you access to the data as it is being written to the file.

You will have to do the same thing for `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` to get the final piece of data.

Comment: Totally agree with the hammer and screw metaphor. Will Try your hack. DownloadTask really sucks without intermediate access to the downloading data.